# Zip -r and wants to exclude/ignore files with no read permission

Tags: permissions, zip

I have a folder with write-only files, and would like to exclude them while zipping.

I don't want to see any warnings or errors related to those write-only files.

Please let me know the best way to do this?

Example:

```
sh:~/t12$ ls -l
total 0
--w--w--w- 1 som  som 0 Dec  5 05:59 a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 som  som 0 Dec  5 05:59 b
-rw-rw-r-- 1 som  som 0 Dec  5 05:59 c

sh:~/t12$ zip -r zipFileName /home/som/t12/*
  adding: home/som/t12/a
zip warning: Permission denied
    zip warning: could not open for reading: home/som/t12/a
  adding: home/som/t12/b (stored 0%)
  adding: home/som/t12/c (stored 0%)

zip warning: Not all files were readable
  files/entries read:  2 (0 bytes)  skipped:  1 (0 bytes)
```

Comment: Do you know the write-only files ahead of time?

Answer (score 4):

I would try something similar to:

```
find . -readable -type f -exec zip -q zipFileName {} +
```

The command:

```
find . -readable -type f
```

returns all files under `.` with read permissions.

The second part

```
-exec zip -q zipFileName {} +
```

executes the `zip` command supplying the filename(s) found.

Comment: Thanks this works like charm for me. Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, on Alpine, the `-readable` option is not available.

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid the warnings by giving `zip` an expanded list of files that you can read.

In zsh, this would be:

```
zip -r zipFileName /home/som/t12/**/*(.r)
```

Without changing to zsh as your shell, you could invoke:

```
zsh -c 'zip -r zipFileName /home/som/t12/**/*(.r)'
```

The wildcard patterns after `/home/som/t12/` are:

- `**/*` -- enable recursion, so that every file and directory are expanded into the list
- `(.r)` -- a glob qualifier that limits the expanded list to plain files (with `.`) and -- crucially for this question -- ones that are readable by the current user (with `r`).

The end result is that the `zip` command-line is:

```
zip -r zipFileName home/som/t12/b home/som/t12/c ...
```

... where `...` is the list of (plain) files under that directory that are readable by you.

One side effect here is that the wildcard expansion does not explicitly match directories, so while your previous `zip -r zipFileName /home/som/t12/` would have included directory entries in the zip file, the above solution will not. The files in those subdirectories will still be present with their full paths in the zip file.

---

If you happen to know the write-only filenames ahead of time, you could tell `zip` to exclude them with:

```
zip -r zipFileName /home/som/t12/ -x /home/som/t12/a -x /home/som/t12/any/other/files ...
```

... where the `-x` flag tells `zip` which file(s) to exclude; be sure to match their path to the path you give for zip.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to generate a list of files you want to compress with `find`, and then pass them to `zip` with the `-@` option.

For example, consider a layout like this:

```
$ ls -l . test2/
.:
total 0
--w--w--w-  1 testuser testuser 0 Dec  5 21:26 a
-rw-rw-r--  1 testuser testuser 0 Dec  5 21:26 b
-rw-rw-r--  1 testuser testuser 0 Dec  5 21:26 c
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 testuser testuser 0 Dec  5 21:31 test2

test2/:
total 0
--w--w--w- 1 testuser testuser 0 Dec  5 21:31 a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 testuser testuser 0 Dec  5 21:26 b
-rw-rw-r-- 1 testuser testuser 0 Dec  5 21:26 c
```

The `find` command can then be used to exclude the files of the write-only permission type (222 in octal form).

```
$ find . -type f ! -perm 222
./b
./c
./test2/b
./test2/c
```

Pass these files on to `zip` to compress them to an archive:

```
$ find . -type f ! -perm 222 | zip myfile.zip -@
  adding: b (stored 0%)
  adding: c (stored 0%)
  adding: test2/b (stored 0%)
  adding: test2/c (stored 0%)
```

And to verify your archive:

```
$ unzip -l myfile.zip
Archive:  myfile.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  12-05-2019 21:26   b
        0  12-05-2019 21:26   c
        0  12-05-2019 21:26   test2/b
        0  12-05-2019 21:26   test2/c
---------                     -------
        0                     4 files
```

Do keep in mind that the `find` command can break here, if your filenames contain an embedded newline character. Spaces are not a problem, since the `-@` options parses each line of output as one file.

Comment: This will fail with files which have a permission other than 222 but are still unreadable (*e.g.* 200, 204, 333, etc.).

Comment: @StephenKitt My intent was to add an answer with the `find .. | zip -@` approach. If we assume that the owner of the files is executing the `zip` command, a different test such as `-perm -u=r` (owner has read rights) could be used to exclude unreadable files with the permissions you've mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs and will try this way